# Get the equation of the plot of the response of the transfer function

Tags: laplace-transform, matlab, control-theory, inverse-laplace

In the case of permanent magnet DC motor position control, I wanted to rotate my motor shaft along a reference trajectory. Then I designed a piecewise function for reference and simulated the response (actual trajectory) using Matlab. Now I need to get the equation of the response curve to analyze the current and voltage behavior. This is the response curve code for Matlab.

```
kp = 10;
kd = 1.3;
kp1 = 5;
pi = 3.14;
y = @(x) (50*pi*x) .* (0<x & x<1/150) +  (pi/3) .* ((1/150<=x) & (x<=3001/150)) + ((3002*pi/3-50*pi*x) .* ((3001/150 <= x) & (x < 1501/75)));%r(t)
x = -1:1/15000:40
sys = tf([0.7274*kd 0.7274*kp],[0.00072 0.07206 0.44244+0.7274*kd 0.7274*kp]);%designed PD control
lsim(sys,y(x),x)%plot of Actual Trajectory with designed control
```

Now I need to plot the response of $v(t)$ according to the response of actual trajectory. 
The relationship between the actual trajectory and the $v(s)$ is,

## **$v(s) = \frac{(0.00072)S^3+(0.07206)S^2+(0.44244)s}{0.7274}\theta(s)$**

Finally, What I need to get is $\theta(s)$ which is equal to the actual trajectory. 
 when I get $\theta(s)$, I can plot voltage response using this,

```
pi = 3.14
syms s
tf  = ((0.00072*s^3+0.07206*s^2+0.44244*S)/(0.7274))*__Theta(s)__;
h = ilaplace(tf)
t = linspace(0,20,50000);   %500 is number of samples to plot
hfun = matlabFunction(h);
plot(t, hfun(t));
hold on;
```

Comment: What is your $\theta(t)$? Why are you defining your own pi if Matlab already has a pi constant? You should rather consider typing your equations. It is not clear what you have and how you want to solve it.

Comment: $\theta(t)$ is the inverse of the $\theta(s)$. What I want is  $\theta(s)$ from the firstcode.

Comment: I do not see any theta in your first code fragment.

Comment: yes, $\theta(t)$ should be the response of the first code. In other words, I need to get the output of this as an equation of s.`lsim(sys,y(x),x)%plot of Actual Trajectory with designed control`

Comment: Can't you just multiply the transfer functions in the first and second code block? I believe this yields a effective transfer function which has one order higher in the numerator then in the denominator which is non-causal, so you also have to provide the derivative of the input.

Comment: I'm a newbie to Matlab. Actually what I  need is, I have a piecewise continuous function called `y = @(x) (50*pi*x) .* (0<x & x<1/150) +  (pi/3) .* ((1/150<=x) & (x<=3001/150)) + ((3002*pi/3-50*pi*x) .* ((3001/150 <= x) & (x < 1501/75)));%r(t) ` and This is the referance trajectory. Also, I know the transfer function. Using this transfer function and referance, I can plot the actual trajectory which is also called as response. Now I need to see the variation of voltage according to this actual trajectory. In lapsase form, $v(s) = \frac{(0.00072)S^3+(0.07206)S^2+(0.44244)s}{0.7274}θ(s)$

Comment: Cross-posted on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56206771/get-the-equation-of-the-plot-of-the-responce-of-the-trantsfer-function

Comment: Have you got any solution or any hint? If you have a way to get a transfer function response as an equation, please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know $G_1(s)$ and $G_2(s)$, the transfer functions from $r(s)$ to $\theta(s)$ and from $\theta(s)$ to $v(s)$ respectively, you can combine them

$$
\frac{v(s)}{r(s)} = G_1(s)\,G_2(s).
$$

However the order of the numerator of $G_1(s)\,G_2(s)$ is one high then the order of the denominator, so this transfer function would not be causal/proper. However one can factor out a $s$ from $G_2(s)$, which essentially means you have to differentiate $r(t)$, which gives

$$
\frac{v(s)}{\dot{r}(s)} = \frac{G_1(s)\,G_2(s)}{s},
$$

which is causal/proper. So now you only have to differentiate your reference signal defined in `y = @(x)` with respect to time, which is `x` in your case. After this you can obtain $v(t)$ using `lsim()` using the transfer function from $\dot{r}(t)$ to $v(t)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your great clarification.